# Is there a way to fix IIS issue regarding the HTTP 404 error code in Laravel Project?

Tags: laravel, iis

Just recently have a problem with my server, I'm using Laravel for my website and it really did go well for a long time but then a problem came in, it seems that whenever I need to access another PHP view file that is not the `index.php` it gives me an `HTTP 404 Error Code` but when I add an **index.php** after the domain like this `https://example.com/index.php/about` it actually loads the page. I've been looking for solutions on the internet but it seems I still can't find one.

Here is my Web.config

```
<rewrite>
<rules>
    <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*"/>
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
    </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:0}"/>
    </rule>
    <rule name="RedirectToHTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)"/>
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true"/>
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://{SERVER_NAME}/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent"/>
    </rule>
    <rule name="RedirectWwwToNonWww" stopProcessing="false">
        <match url="(.*)"/>
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)(.*)$"/>
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://{R:0}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent"/>
    </rule>
    <rule name="RedirectNonWwwToWww" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)"/>
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example.com$"/>
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent"/>
    </rule>
    <rule name="LowercaseAllUrls" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*[A-Z].*" ignoreCase="false"/>
        <action type="Redirect" url="{ToLower:{R:0}}"/>
    </rule>
</rules>
```

here is the error I'm getting

[image]

Comment: the index.php should not be in your URL... every request needs to point to index.php (if the file does not exist)

Comment: I also tried removing the `index.php` on the `<action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:0}"/>` but it didn't work also

Comment: does this help? https://forum.yiiframework.com/t/my-way-to-hide-index-php-on-iis-7/82456 . It's about yii, but basically the same problem

Comment: tried the solution above but it didn't work, it seems IIS can't find the other resource files for each views. Still looking for solutions online

Comment: Use FRT to learn where the 404 responses come from first, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules. BTW, the order of the rules matter in most cases, so once you know the cause reordering the rules might be the solution.

Comment: Use failed request tracing to troubleshoot url rewrite. It will show you which rule causes 404 error. Check the sub status code.

Comment: I will try using FRT, was ready to reset the server maybe there was a misconfiguration on the IIS.

Comment: Also there is no `Rewrite` on the `WWW Server`, is this normal?

Comment: This is the error I'm getting `Module: IIS Web Core 
Notification: MapRequestHandler
Handler: StaticFile
Error Code: 0x80070002`

Comment: This is not the error message of Url rewrite. This error can be fixed by add index.php in URL. So use frt to check the process of url rewrite. You need check if these rewrite rules work successfully.

Comment: I already triedtesting the url rewrite and they work successfully, I'm really having a lot of trouble resolving this issue since it just happened unexpectedly.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, it was the web.config all along, what I did was I installed a fresh laravel project and added it to my IIS Server, and then copied the web.config from the fresh laravel project and pasted it onto the other web.config and it fixed it.